animate not works in mini ipad and mobile
$(".section-form .form-wrap").hide();
$(".thank-you-content-wrap").show();
var $sectionForm = $('.section-form');
var stickyHeaderHeight = 85;
var offset = $sectionForm.offset().top - stickyHeaderHeight;
console.log('offset', offset);
setTimeout(() => {
  if ($sectionForm.length > 0) {
    var stickyHeaderHeight = 85;
    var offset = $sectionForm.offset().top - stickyHeaderHeight;
    console.log('offset', offset);
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: offset
    }, 'slow');
  }
}, 1100);

The animate  behaves differently for mini iPad (below 1023px) and mobile why?
Work on all devices with the same behaviour

Did you try debug and see where it goes wrong. Does $sectionForm.length return more than 0 or does something else break.

@CarstenLøvboAndersen $sectionForm.length returns 1 value.
I have debug the code on mobile devices every time change offset value.
I have call the above code in         $(document).ready(function () {}) function and added 1100 milli second for delay but still same issue happens.
The above 1024 devices its works as expected.

Perhaps there is a media query that changes what is returned when <1023px?

@mplungjan Media query used in css not in any js file.

I know, but it can hide stuff or move it using positions and remove sticky etc
